How do I verify the CAL's installed in Windows Server 2016?
I've got a Windows Server 2016 Standard server. I know we've previously bought various batches of CAL's (user licenses). But I'm unsure how many total have been bought. I have administrative access to the server - is there a way to tell how many user CAL's have been installed?
I've looked all around in Server Manager, and see mentions of a 'Licenses Manager' online, but can't find any such thing. (is this even possible?)

You need to run cscript.exe %systemroot%\system32\slmgr.vbs /dlv. On your server that is running the license service and where you registered the CALs. The license server also registers itself in DNS with a SRV record for port 1677.
